# Need Suggestion HD Camera to be integrated with Wifi module

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, digital-cameras, esp32

I am working on one of my IoT project which needs to wide angle HD camera modules to integrated with Wifi Modules (open to Raspberry Pi, NodeMCU or anything else).

I have checked various options but could not figure out which is the best HD camera options should I go for.

I am looking for following:

- Capture the live feed and show over internet
- Store 5 to 10 secs video and then upload to server
- Need night vision capability
- Need HD and wide angle camera
- Easy integration as I would need to use PIR sensors to activate camera

If anyone has experience working with HD camera modules which can be integrated with wifi modules. Kindly provide your suggestions.

Comment: You've asked for a wifi camera, but the pi is itself wifi and you could have a USB cam hooked up to your wifi pi. The pi would show you your video stream in a browser. WDYT?

Comment: You may want to consider this or other similar products https://www.wired.com/2014/10/hd-streamer-boxes/

Answer (score 2):

**Haiworld**
**Features:**

- Wide Angle Camera Module,
- Name: Haiworld New Version
- 5 Megapixel 1080p Fisheye Lens
- Infrared LED Light Night Vision  Supported for Raspberry Pi 3 model B
  B+ A+ RPi 2, Rpi 1
- Item Height  35 Millimeters
- Item Width   6 Centimeters
- Item Weight  31.8 g
- Product Dimensions   10 x 6 x 3.5 cm
- Computer Memory Type    DRAM

It is available on Amazon with good reviews [Check out](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B01MYUOQ0A/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_1?pf_rd_p=cd818f9c-142a-4b42-ad2c-f0421857aaf5&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=B00N1YJKFS&pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_r=XFZCRQ33C39SM9NM1H6S&pf_rd_r=XFZCRQ33C39SM9NM1H6S&pf_rd_p=cd818f9c-142a-4b42-ad2c-f0421857aaf5) .

If you are stuck please post a question or comment on this thread as we can help you out

Comment: Just posting a link to a camera on Amazon doesn't really help, please edit the answer to explain why this is suitable